# How do I convert lines of words into a single array

Tags: java, parsing

For example, I want to turn this list:

> dog cat
>
> trees breeze
>
> ...

which has a definite amount of lines with two words in each into a single array.

How do I do this using `BufferedReader`? The problem is I don't know how to continue parsing for say x times without a `for` loop or something. How would I do it with a `for` loop?

Here is sample code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.in"));
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("input.out")));
static int[] words
for (int i=1; i<2N; i+2) {
    StringTokenizer i 
        words[i] = String.parsestring}
}
}
```

Comment: Easy: read in each line, split on whitespace, and add both words to a list.  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: Please show what code you have so far, so we can help you.

Comment: Good to see some code to work with. However it looks like code that will not even compile. Have you managed to get it to run? And step through it using your debugger?

Answer (score 1):

If you are having trouble using a `BufferedReader` to go through line by line you could use a `Scanner` instead and assuming the file is not very big scan the whole file into a string and subsequently use [split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) to obtain an array of all the words in the file:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class ArrayFromFile{
    public static void main(String []args){
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"))) {
            String text = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next(); //Get contents of file as String
            String[] words = text.split(" "); 

            for(String word : words) //Printing out the elements in the array
                System.out.println(word);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if is this what you need, but in java 8 can be done like this:
assuming we have a text file like this:

```
cat dog
mouse zebra
goat bear
lizard carrot
car truck
bus bike
```

we can use java 8 streams to get all content and place it into an set:

```
Set<String> set_text = Files.lines(Paths.get("/data2/test/data.txt")).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

then we parse the set to an array:

```
String[] arr = set_text.toArray(new String[set_text.size()]);

for(String text : arr)
{
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

if this is not what you need, let me know to edit it :)